# Does the adjoint of an Operator with finite dimensional Kernel have finite dimensional Kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis

While studying a solution i've encountered the statement that by point (b.) it follows that $Kernel(A)$ and $Kernel(A')$ are finite dimensional, where $A$ is a linear Operator between Banach spaces and $A'$ its adjoint.

In point (b.) it was proven that $Kernel(A)$ is indeed finite dimensional. Also did get proven that an inequality $||x|| \leq C||Ax||$ holds für all $x\in X$ (especially of course for $x \in Ker(A)$.

My questions:
1.) If A has finite Kernel, does it directly follow that its adjoint has finite Kernel?
Intuitively that doesnt seem true at all to me.

2.) Is there a way to conclude from the inequality that $Ker(A')$ has finite dimensions?

Its stated like its super obvious but i dont see it at all, so i would be thankful for some help.

Comment: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $v\in H$, the map $\Bbb C\to H, z\mapsto z v$ has finite dimensional kernel. The adjoint is $H\to \Bbb C$, $w\mapsto \langle w,v\rangle$ which does not have finite dimensional kernel. 2. The inequality $\|x\|\leq C\|Ax\|$ implies that the kernel is actually $0$, but is not enough to connclude that the adjoint has finite dimensional kernel, since this property also holds for map defined above.

Comment: It is not true for $B(\mathcal{H}).$ There are injective operators whose image has no finite codimension. For example $\mathcal{H}=\ell^2$ and $A\delta_n=\delta_{2n}.$ The adjoint operator is given by $A^*\delta_{2n}=\delta_n,$ $A^*\delta_{2n+1}=0.$